# setlocale() not working on localhost using MAMP on MacOS

Tags: php, localhost, mamp, setlocale

My problem in short: I am using `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE")` in order to display the "verbal" parts of a date/time (i.e. month, weekday) in German. This works on any public server, but *doesn't* on my localhost, using MAMP, which displays it in English instead of German.

---

In detail:

I have the following code (nothing else in the file, I reduced it to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue):

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de_DE'>
    <head>
        <title>Datum in Deutsch</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>
                <?php 
                echo "Heute ist ";
                echo strftime("%A, der %e. %B %Y");
                ?>
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This *should*  be displayed as

> Heute ist Donnerstag, der 10. Juni 2021

But on my localhost/MAMP, it *is* displayed as

> Heute ist Thursday, der 10. June 2021

As I mentioned: If I upload this file to any public server and open it, it *is*  displayed as desired (i.e. with the German expressions)

---

I have searched SO and other websites for a solution. An advice I found several times was to check if the German locale is installed at all on my system.

So I opened the terminal (I am on MacOS 10.14.6) and typed "locale -a": The list of returned and installed locales *includes* `de_DE`  (among many others).

I also found the advice to include this line in the code to check whether the desired locale is available, which I did:

```
<?php echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); ?>
```

This outputs "C/C/C/C/de_DE/C " , so again, `de_DE` *is*  included (but won't give me a localized date display).

My system: MacOS 10.14.6, MAMP 6.3 as local Apache server, running PHP 7.4.12 (switching to PHP 8.0 changes nothing)

Edit/additional info: I previously had used AMPPS as a local server on the same system, where this worked. So to me it seems to be a MAMP issue.

What can I do to make it work? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Just confirming likely MAMP issue. I'm getting the expected string `Juni` on XAMPP (PHP 7.3.9, Mac OS with `de_DE` included in `locale -a`).

Comment: Did you try "de_DE.UTF-8" as locale value? That makes a difference on my machines, "de_DE" renders english, "de_DE.UTF-8" german text;

Comment: @TomRegner I just tried that, but it doesn't help - here that also renders English :-( Are you doing that on MAMP?

Comment: No, just something that bit me in the past. You have a workaround, that's something, but there should be a way to generate/activate a German locale for the virtual host environment MAMP sets up -- or it should 'just work', this is a frustrating situation IMHO

Comment: @TomRegner Yes, it really is...

Comment: Does it format the date in German if you try `LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF8 date +%A` (or without the UTF8 depending on what `locale -a` returned) in the Terminal?

Comment: @TobiasK. You mean in the brackets of `strftime()`?

Comment: No, just the `date` command, outside of PHP, in terminal with an envvar, to check if the OS DE locale (PHP just uses that too) works in general.

Comment: @TobiasK. If I write that into the termin (with or without the UTF-8) I get the response "LC_TIME=de_DE: Command not found". But anyway, as I wrote in the question, I previously had used AMPPS as a local server, and at that time the same file worked as expected. (And actually, I just discovered that if i switch from Apache to Nginx in MAMP, it also works as expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php)? This uses [unicode date formatting](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/). View the [example in action](https://www.tehplayground.com/Ph8Z80TtZStr4m3m)

```
$fmt = datefmt_create( "de-DE",
   IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 
   IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
   'Europe/Berlin',
   IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
   "EEEE, 'der' d. LLLL Y");

 echo "Heute ist " . datefmt_format( $fmt ,time());
 //output: Heute ist Freitag, der 18. Juni 2021
```

In context

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de_DE'>
    <head>
        <title>Datum in Deutsch</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>
              <?php 
                $fmt = datefmt_create( "de-DE" , IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Europe/Berlin',IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN  ,"EEEE, 'der' d. LLLL Y");
                echo "Heute ist " . datefmt_format( $fmt ,time());
                ?>
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Updated answer with tested (and testable) code. (I didn't realize it used a different date formatting system.)

Comment: Yes, this works - thank you very much!! I would have preferred to get some kind of fix for MAMP not handling `setlocale` correctly, but this is an adequate replacement. Apparently, the first two lines at the top (`setlocale` and `date_default_timezone_set`) are not needed at all when using this method. I'll award the bounty when the one-week time slot for it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in place of lines 1 to 4:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the resulting output didn't change, weekday and month are still displayed in English. The only thing that changed is that `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` now returns only "de_DE" instead of the previous "C/C/C/C/de_DE/C "

Answer (score 0):

try install/reinstall language package 1st `sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack de_DE` and then set your language using `setlocale()`