# Convert English date in French language

Tags: php, date, datetime, localtime

I get a `$date` from an API in UTC format like `2021-11-13T14:00:14Z`.

So using php I convert it to : 13 November 2021

`$date = strftime(date('d F Y', strtotime($date);`

So now I want to translate it in French.

I am working on local with on macbook pro using MAMP.

My html code setting is :

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I even forced Local Time to :

`setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr', 'fr_FR', 'fr_FR@euro', 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fr-FR', 'fra'); date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');`

But the date remain in english !

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The first argument to `strftime()` must be a format string. Why are you giving it a date that's already formatted using `date('d F Y')?`

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `strftime()` correctly. The first argument must be a format string. `date()` returns an already-formatted date, and it doesn't use locales. This works for me:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr', 'fr_FR', 'fr_FR@euro', 'fr_FR.utf8', 'fr-FR', 'fra');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
$date = "2021-11-13T14:00:14Z";
echo strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar don't help still in English !

Comment: Maybe you don't have the French locale installed on your server? Don't ask me how to check that or fix it, I don't know.

Comment: I think it come from MAMP, this I can do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927006/setlocale-not-working-on-localhost-using-mamp-on-macos

Comment: `strftime()` is deprecated since PHP 8.1. Maybe suggest OP for `IntlDateFormatter` class instead? And about `setlocale()`, PHP have [strange supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312801/128761) for this on different versions.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions based on the [IntlDateFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) work independently of the local installations of the server. Example as already written in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927006/setlocale-not-working-on-localhost-using-mamp-on-macos). When using the class [**dt**](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt), which uses the IntlDateFormatter class, the same format characters can be used for the method formatL as for [DateTime::format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
$dt = dt::create('2021-11-13T14:00:14Z');

//UTC -> localTime "2021-11-13 15:00:14"
$dt->setTimeZone('Europe/Paris');  

echo $dt->formatL('l d F Y H:i','fr');
// samedi 13 novembre 2021 15:00

echo $dt->formatL('l d F Y H:i','de');
// Samstag 13 November 2021 15:00
```

The date string contains the "Z" time zone, which corresponds to UTC.
A new time zone can be set with setTimeZone() to get the local time. If the UTC time (here 14:00) is to be displayed, this line must be omitted. The format method (without L) still exists. This method delivers the result as usual in English.